# upgrading debian jessie KEYEXPIRED

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade

I'm getting the error

W: GPG error: http://http.debian.net jessie Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1668891673

while trying to update my OS.
`/etc/debian_version`:

```
8.11
```

`/etc/sources/list`:

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free

#deb http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-frew
```

`apt-getupdate`:

```
# apt-get clean
# apt-get update
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates Release.gpg
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates Release
Get:1 http://http.debian.net jessie Release.gpg [1,652 B]
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Sources      
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib Sources     
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/non-free Sources    
Hit http://http.debian.net jessie Release                         
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main armhf Packages  
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib armhf Packages
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/non-free armhf Packages
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://http.debian.net jessie Release                          
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Translation-en  
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://http.debian.net jessie/main Sources/DiffIndex          
Ign http://http.debian.net jessie/contrib Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://http.debian.net jessie/non-free Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://http.debian.net jessie/main armhf Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://http.debian.net jessie/contrib armhf Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://http.debian.net jessie/non-free armhf Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://http.debian.net jessie/contrib Translation-en
Hit http://http.debian.net jessie/main Translation-en
Hit http://http.debian.net jessie/non-free Translation-en
Hit http://http.debian.net jessie/main Sources                           
Hit http://http.debian.net jessie/contrib Sources  
Hit http://http.debian.net jessie/non-free Sources 
Hit http://http.debian.net jessie/main armhf Packages
Hit http://http.debian.net jessie/contrib armhf Packages
Hit http://http.debian.net jessie/non-free armhf Packages
Ign http://http.debian.net jessie/contrib Translation-en_US                                                                                              
Ign http://http.debian.net jessie/main Translation-en_US                                                                                                 
Ign http://http.debian.net jessie/non-free Translation-en_US                                                                                             
Fetched 1,652 B in 28s (57 B/s)                                                                                                                          
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://http.debian.net jessie Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1668891673
```

I have downloaded the package `debian-archive-keyring_2021.1.1_all.deb` and tried to install manually:

```
# dpkg -i /home/olimex/debian-archive-keyring_2021.1.1_all.deb 
dpkg-deb: error: archive '/home/olimex/debian-archive-keyring_2021.1.1_all.deb' contains not understood data member control.tar.xz, giving up
dpkg: error processing /home/olimex/debian-archive-keyring_2021.1.1_all.deb (--install):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /home/olimex/debian-archive-keyring_2021.1.1_all.deb
```

What should I try?

Comment: Dunno how topical this is but try https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/fxozpt/comment/fmw2bkr/

Comment: If jessie didn't support xz at the time, then dpkg won't be able to install it. It's still easy to retrieve the content: ar, xz and tar are the only commands needed. Anyway, with jessie EOL, whatever effort spent on this would be better spent on using a more recent Debian release (though there's some [ELTS](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Extended) support).

Answer (score 0):

you have to write your sources.list to change to :
http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/

Like :

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main non-free
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main non-free
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-archive/debian-security/ jessie updates/main non-free
```

Comment: Your answer is a bit terse and could be improved by explaining the issue, i.e., the underlying cause of the problem and why your solution correctly would resolve it for the user in the question.